# Alternatives for "hold all"

Tags: matlab, plot

I use "hold all" as a equivalent for "hold on" when I want to generate graphs of different colours. However, MathWorks  website says that "hold all" would not be available in future releases.(http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)

My question is: Are there any non tedious alternatives to "hold all" that we could use to plot graphs of different colours? (Especially for plot functions embedded within for loops - they become rather difficult to use colour specifiers)

Comment: `hold all` is not in future releases because from 2014b on the default behaviour will be changed to cycle through colours when `hold on` is called. In other words, `hold on` will now do what `hold all` used to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) definition for Matlab R2014b I find:

> `hold on` retains plots in the current axes so that new plots added to
>   the axes do not delete existing plots. **New plots use the next colors
>   and line styles based on the ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder properties
>   of the axes**. MATLAB® adjusts axes limits, tick marks, and tick labels
>   to display the full range of data.

and indeed later on:

> `hold all` is the same as `hold on`. This syntax will be removed in a
>   future release. Use hold on instead.

So bottom line, don't worry, just use `hold on` when you upgrade to the latest version.